# Group configuration in quarkus / microprofile

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile

I want to group configuration items in Quarkus and use them as a `Map`. Something along the lines of the next `application.properties`:

```
greeting.names = tom,jane
greeting.tom.message = hello
greeting.tom.name = tom
greeting.jane.message = hi
greeting.jane.name = jane
```

And have them in the application in a `Map`, like this:

```java
@ConfigProperties
public class GreetingConfig {

   private String name;
   private String message;

   // getters / setters
}
```

And use them like this:

```java
private Map<String, GreetingConfig> config;
```

They are now name indexed, but a `List` would also be fine (and is what I actually need):

```
greeting.1.message = hello
greeting.1.name = tom
greeting.2.message = hi
greeting.2.name = jane
```

Any ideas on how to realize this? I have a programmatic solution, but would prefer a solution by annotation only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem these days. 
So I wrote a simple Quarkus extension which helped me with the configuration.
You can use the guides from the Quarkus site: [Quarkus - Writing Your Own Extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions) and [Quarkus - Building my first extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension),
but basically these are the steps taken in order to create the configuration:

1. Have some `maven` multi module project (not the project where the configuration will be consumed).
2. Execute a similar command form the project directory:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:create-extension -N \
    -Dquarkus.artifactIdBase=keycloak-extension \
    -Dquarkus.artifactIdPrefix=otaibe-commons-quarkus- \
    -Dquarkus.nameBase="Keycloak extension"
```

This will create 'sub multi module' project there with the following modules: `runtume` and `deployment`.

3. Go to the `runtime` module and add and annotate your config class. It should be something similar to [this class](https://github.com/tpenakov/otaibe-commons-quarkus/blob/master/keycloak-extension/deployment/src/main/java/org/otaibe/commons/quarkus/keycloak/extension/deployment/KeycloakExtensionProcessor.java)
4. In `runtime` module create a [`producer`](https://github.com/tpenakov/otaibe-commons-quarkus/blob/master/keycloak-extension/runtime/src/main/java/org/otaibe/commons/quarkus/keycloak/extension/config/OtaibeKeycloakQuarkusProducer.java) class which should register the configuration class as CDI bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OtaibeKeycloakQuarkusProducer {

    private volatile OtaibeKeycloakConfig otaibeKeycloakConfig;

    void initialize(OtaibeKeycloakConfig config) {
        this.otaibeKeycloakConfig = config;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Produces
    public OtaibeKeycloakConfig otaibeKeycloakConfig() {
        return otaibeKeycloakConfig;
    }

}
```

5. Create a [`Recorder`](https://github.com/tpenakov/otaibe-commons-quarkus/blob/master/keycloak-extension/runtime/src/main/java/org/otaibe/commons/quarkus/keycloak/extension/config/OtaibeKeycloakRecorder.java) class which should initialize the `Producer`:

```
@Recorder
public class OtaibeKeycloakRecorder {

    public void initOtaQuarkusProducer(BeanContainer container, OtaibeKeycloakConfig configuration) {
        OtaibeKeycloakQuarkusProducer producer = container.instance(OtaibeKeycloakQuarkusProducer.class);
        producer.initialize(configuration);
    }

}
```

6. In `deployment` module you have a `Processor` class. Go there and register your `Producer` to be injectable as CDI bean and your `Recorder` to initialize it. Add the similar code:

```
    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem beans() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder().addBeanClasses(OtaibeKeycloakQuarkusProducer.class).build();
    }

    @BuildStep
    @Record(ExecutionTime.RUNTIME_INIT)
    void otaibeKeycloackConfigBuildItem(BeanContainerBuildItem beanContainer,
                                        OtaibeKeycloakConfig otaibeKeycloakConfig,
                                        OtaibeKeycloakRecorder recorder) {
        recorder.initOtaQuarkusProducer(beanContainer.getValue(), otaibeKeycloakConfig);
    }
```

You can find my implementation [here](https://github.com/tpenakov/otaibe-commons-quarkus/blob/master/keycloak-extension/deployment/src/main/java/org/otaibe/commons/quarkus/keycloak/extension/deployment/KeycloakExtensionProcessor.java).

7. Now, go to your initial project where the configuration will be consumed and add the `runtime` module as a dependency.
8. In order to ensure that the configuration is added properly execute the following `maven` command:

```
mvn quarkus:generate-config
```

Now, you can check the file `src/main/resources/application.properties.example` and verify whether your properties are added there. The property group should start with `quarkus.` plus the name of your `@ConfigRoot` annotation. In my case for example it will start with `quarkus.otaibe.keycloak`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Now in Quarkus 2.9, you do it with `@ConfigMapping` (`@ConfigProperties` is deprecated).

```java
@StaticInitSafe
@ConfigMapping
public interface GreetingConfigMapping {
    Map<Integer, GreetingDetail> greeting();
}

interface GreetingDetail {
    String name();
    String message();
}
```

Try it in a `@QuarkusTest`; `@Inject` it.